# sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'where'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to sum a vector with bool condition with `np.sum()`.

it works on google colab but not on local.
Here is my line of code :

```
np.sum([[0, 1], [np.nan, 5]], where=[False, True], axis=1)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Likely your `numpy` version is older than 1.17.

Comment: You can check your numpy version using `np.__version__`

Comment: `np.add.reduce(...)` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`where=…`** parameter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy-sum) has been added since [numpy-1.17](/questions/tagged/numpy-1.17), so you should upgrade the numpy package, for example with:

```
pip3 install numpy --upgrade
```